# Jquery autocomplete select event issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Ajax autocomplete response values are not coming to select option to display the text in the filed. Please advise how to get the value in select event.

```
$("#parts").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
$.ajax({
url: "searchPart.jsp",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: { name: request.term},
success: function (data) {
        tempResults = data;
       response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
            return {
                label: key,
                value: key
            };
        }));
        }
      });
},
minLength: 3,
select: function (event, ui) {
 //event.preventDefault();
var name = tempResults[ui.item.value].value;
var id = tempResults[ui.item.value].key;

$('#partname').val(name);
$('#partname').text(name);
}  
}); 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="part" id="parts" />
<input type="text" name="partname" id=partname/>
```

Comment: Checked your console for errors?

Comment: No errors , just value and key both coming as autocomplete suggestion..

Comment: Are you sure you want to `preventDefault()` in `select()`? Per [the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), that will prevent that value from being filled in in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select()` event handler is in the `ajax()` call, not the `autocomplete()` call. If you tell your editor to fix your indentation that will be obvious.

Comment: Now getting trigger the select option.but response values are not assigning to text field. Please advise.

Comment: Did you see my comment about `preventDefault()` above?